# Three column HTML table layout with a main column

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a 3 column table with the main content displayed in the middle content.
All three column's widths are flexible but the middle column width must take priority.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems relatively simple, so I might well be missing something, but given the following html:

#### html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="left">Some content</td>
        <td id="center">Center content</td>
        <td id="right">Right content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some content</td>
        <td>Center content</td>
        <td>Right content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### and css:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 90%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#center {
    width: 70%;
}
```

The key to this working is the defined `width` on the `table` itself, and then on the `td` of `id="center"` (and tables apply a consistent width to all cells in the same 'column', and height of cells in the same 'row', unless `colspan` or `rowspan` forces different behaviour). [JS Fiddle demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hJZ6Q/](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hJZ6Q/).

The 'columns' (defined by `#left` and `#right`) are left without an explicit width, which causes the browser to assign an equal width to both, in this case that's about 15% of the width of the table. You can, of course, assign a width of whatever unit you want to the 'columns', so long as the total fits within the assigned width of the `table` itself (as negative numbers are invalid for table widths, and assigning such a number will cause the browser to disregard the width, and simply work with whatever valid widths remain).

Comment: The problem I find when setting the column width to 70% is that it will squash the other columns even if their content requires more space.

Comment: Yes; the problem is that there's no way of setting precedence in CSS, you **can't** say 'this column at 70%, *unless* this other column requires a bit more, this time'. You have to find a balance you're prepared to live with, **or** use JavaScript to try and implement a more versatile solution.

Comment: OK thanks. I think I'll just use a fixed width div layout instead and just adjust the widths for different pages.

Answer (score 2):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="left">Some content</td>
        <td id="center">Center content</td>
        <td id="right">Right content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap">Some content</td>
        <td style="width:90%">Center content</td>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap">Right content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This seems to work well for me.  It uses no wrap to force the small columns to expand beyond the 5% each column is given and gives the rest of the space to the middle column.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you take a look at [Perfect 3 Column Layout](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm)
It's a liquid layout and sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: If your just trying to change one column why not just make the width a percentage of how much of the page you want it to take up and add !important to the width. It would be helpful if you could provide the code your trying to change..